# Where does Microsoft RDP 8 for Mac store its configuration

Tags: remote-desktop, microsoft

I want to find a way to share some Microsoft RDP configuration information with my team.

Where does Microsoft RDP 8 for Mac store its connections and configuration?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If you want to share a configuration you can select the target under My Desktops and either right-click and select Export or from the Microsoft Remote Desktop File menu select Export.

The file that contains the information shown in the Microsoft Remote Desktop window, sans any passwords which are stored in your Keychain, is located at:

```
/Users/$USER/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.rdc.mac/Data/Library/Preferences/com.microsoft.rdc.mac.plist
```

For MS RDP 10, I had to copy two folders:
/Users/~/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.rdc.mac
/Users/~/Library/Containers/Microsoft Remote Desktop

Hope this helps...

Comment: Cannot seem to find this folder in High Sierra?

Comment: @Brian D, I just installed Microsoft Remote Desktop, 8.0.43 (Build 27325), in macOS High Sierra and it's still in the same location as stated in my answer. As far as I can tell, nothing has changed in this respect and what's stated in my answer is still valid and applicable.

Comment: @user3439894 I'm an idiot and looked for it in the GUI rather than terminal.  You're right

Comment: @Brian D, While one certainly can access it from Terminal, nonetheless it is still accessible from Finder. Press the Option key while clicking the Go menu in Finder and Library will appear.

Comment: I do not see the passwords stored in this file. Where are the passwords stored?

Comment: @BlackSheep, Passwords are stored in the User's Keychain and can be seen in the Keychain Access.app in /Applications/Utilities/.

Comment: how does one import this into the new RDP 10.?

Comment: For RDP 10, there is a file named: `com.microsoft.rdc.macos.plist` - note `macos` instead of `mac`. Tried replacing the file with a backup after deleting some profiles and didn't restore.

Comment: Note that this does not appear to be correct in Microsoft Remote Desktop 10.x.  You have to click every machine and go to `Connections` -> `Export to RDP file...`.

Comment: In my mac ok the path was /Users/$USER/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.rdc.macos/Data/Library/Preferences/com.microsoft.rdc.macos.plist