# How do I make the Microsoft RDP client for Mac play nice with Windows 10?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

Been beating my head against a brick wall trying to connect to my Windows 10 Pro workstation using Microsoft's RDP client for Mac. The symptoms I'm seeing (black screen or frozen screen) are very similar to the issues I had using mstsc.exe on a Win 7 machine. The Windows solution to the bug so far is to turn off [Persistent Bitmap Caching](https://superuser.com/questions/6962/what-does-the-bitmap-caching-option-do-in-the-remote-desktop-client) in the Experience settings. Even this doesn't work for everyone.

Sadly, I can't find any exposed settings to turn off that feature in the Mac client.

- It's not exposed in the App or menus.
- No mention of it in the [plist file located at](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/182209/where-does-microsoft-rdp-8-for-mac-store-its-configuration/182258#182258?newreg=c8a5e12897c540d2a9dc6d97cc388e9b):

  ```
  /Users/$USER/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.rdc.mac/
  Data/Library/Preferences/com.microsoft.rdc.mac.plist
  ```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the bitmap caching was an option with earlier versions of RDC on the Mac; but according to [this link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/b9f1387c-e736-4cc5-b95b-2dd1cfa3cac0/osx-microsoft-remote-desktop-disable-bitmap-caching?forum=winRDc), it is no longer possible to change this.

**Duplicate IPs**

Are there conflicting IPs on the network?

A possible cause I've seen given these symptoms is duplicate IPs. Duplicate IPs on either the Windows 10 box or the Mac can cause this issue.

Try refresh the IP (assuming DHCP) on one or both sides and monitor the stability.

Comment: Thanks Niall. I suppose all that's left to do now is crack I open a beer and lament my misfortune.