# Migration Assistant move from Yosemite to Sierra: keyboard and trackpad behaviour different when using Microsoft Remote Desktop

Tags: macos, keyboard, remote-desktop, migration

I've done a Migration Assistant move of my apps/data/settings from a Yosemite machine to a Sierra machine.

After that I verified that all my "System Preferences" keyboard shortcut settings and trackpad settings had been copied over (they are; I had disabled most of them so Microsoft Remote Desktop gets all keys and mouse events)

On the Sierra machine, somehow these are note forwarded correctly:

- Option-Space
- Secondary-Click

With "Yosemite", both will get you the Windows "right mouse button" behaviour (firing up the context menu).

On "Sierra", this the resulting behaviour

- Option-Space will get a blank space
- Secondary-Click will paste the clipboard

How can I force Sierra to forward them as-sis to the Microsoft Remote Desktop session?

I'm using a "US" keyboard on both Yosemite and Sierra.

I've reproduced this issue with:

- Microsoft Remote Desktop.8.0.23
- Microsoft Remote Desktop.8.0.26
- Microsoft Remote Desktop.8.0.29
- Microsoft Remote Desktop.8.0.35
- Microsoft Remote Desktop.8.0.36

Answer (score 1):

It might be worth trying the latest RDC 8.2 beta from [Technet :Remote Desktop Client Preview for Mac supports multiple monitors and more](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/enterprisemobility/2016/03/30/remote-desktop-client-preview-for-mac-supports-multiple-monitors-and-more/)

Even though it is still a beta, it offers several significant improvements over the existing release version. I've been using it for months without seeing any real issues.

Key improvements

- Multiple monitor support
- Copy and Paste files using Cmd or Ctrl C/X/V
- Direct connectivity to desktops as well as connectivity through a Remote Desktop Gateway
- A new user interface together with a redesigned user accounts experience that includes unified management
- High quality video and audio streaming
- Import of .rdp files into the app and export of connections as .rdp files
- New features like the ability to group desktops and to copy and paste images and files

Comment: Thanks I will try. Does it automagically recognise the remote desktop connections I've setup in 8.0.x? If not: can it import them?

Comment: tbh, I've been using it so long I don't remember how I loaded mine, whether it was automagic or not, but it can import old files for sure.

Comment: where does the new version store the settings? (so I can try to see where I can hunt down the settings for the old version).

Comment: I think you need to export them - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/182209/where-does-microsoft-rdp-8-for-mac-store-its-configuration

Comment: I verified with Remote Desktop Beta and still have the same problems.

Comment: Sorry, I've no better idea. I haven't gone to Sierra yet.

Comment: No problem. Any other ideas of apps I could test option key shortcuts with?

Comment: I've verified with VMware Fusion: right click also does a paste, but option-space key does get through.